# Way to merge both grid view and details view behaviour

Tags: asp.net, gridview, detailsview

In my website, I am displaying a receipt to the user. For most of the receipt, a simple details view works well. However, when I get to the items in the order, it only shows the first item returned, which was expected. But I need a way to list all of the items associated with the order. So, I was thinking of having part details view for the 'one' order record in my one-to-many relationship, and for my items, having another control - a grid view.

My question is, is this the only way it can be done, or can I somehow merge the way the two controls work and have the details view retrieve just one order but all associated items?

Answer (score 0):

Initially this is not possible the way you would hope.

But what you can do is to nest a Web User Control to the list view and in that web user control have a details view, to pass an argument to the code behind of the Web User Control you would do it like this.

MainPage.aspx

```
<asp:ListView ID="ItemList">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc1:TestControl runat="server" id="TestControl" Example='<%# Eval("DetailsViewID")%>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

on the User Control TestControl.ascx.cs you can access the Example attribute by calling

```
Public string Example { get; set;}
```

then you can build the details view on the TestControl.ascx from code behind